# Can't find a bin folder inside MySQL folder?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So I have installed MySQL Workbench 8.0. When I start the program I see the following (shown in the picture below). I've looked for a way to solve this online, but I can't find MySQL network in Windows Services, and I don't even have the bin folder in MySQL folder.

Can somebody help me?

[image]

Comment: MySQL Workbench is just a client. MySQL Server is a separate product, and would be installed separately. You don't necessarily need MySQL Server installed on the local computer with MySQL Workbench, because you might use Workbench only to access remote MySQL Server instances. Click the "(+)" button next to "MySQL Connections" to configure connections to remote instances. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-new.html

Comment: I want to use that to connect to my react app. I've created a network but it shows that server status has stopped. Can I connect it this way anyhow to my backend? I'm learning about MySQL and Backend using this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=re3OIOr9dJI.

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a client for MySQL Server, not a React app.